# Boost Installation

Tags: linux, boost, installation, ubuntu-9.04

I have a question regarding the installation of the boost libraries.  Is there a package that I can use the sudo apt-get install to install this package.  I searched all of the questions in this forum and using the commands `sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-dev` I cannot install theh package with this.  Also, I can download it from boost.org but I do not know the correct path to install it too.  I would prefer to install it using the `sudo apt-get install` commands if possible.  I am using Ubuntu 9.04.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use command `aptitude search libboost` to see list of the availiable boost libraries. The last version of boost is 1.42 - maybe that's why you can't find version 1.40.

If `aptitude search` command don't give you sufficient results, try `sudo aptitude update` and then run `aptitude search` again.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to run with the latest version, you can do the bjam install as mentioned by Ralf, but I suggest you build a 'pseudo' package so you can

- uninstall it safely
- prevent/notice conflicts with official/existing boost packages.

Here is how to do that:

```
mkdir -pv /tmp/boostinst
cd /tmp/boostinst/
wget -c 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.66.0/boost_1_66_0.tar.bz2/download'
tar xf download
cd boost_1_66_0/
./bootstrap.sh --help
./bootstrap.sh --show-libraries
./bootstrap.sh 

checkinstall ./b2 install
```

Comment: Heads up: `bjam` got renamed to b2` for purposes of building boost with boost v.1_48

Comment: `sudo checkinstall ./b2 install` worked after installing libbz2-dev

Comment: plus 1 for checkinstall

Answer (score 17):

On new boost version there is other way:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget -c 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.50.0/boost_1_50_0.tar.bz2/download'
tar xf download
cd boost_1_50_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 install
```

Comment: how can I verify if the boost is correctly installed ?

Answer (score 4):

On my version of Ubuntu (10.04) it's libboost1.40-all-dev

On your version you've probably got an older version of boost, you should just be able to tab-complete to see which version you can install.

In any case what I usually do under Ubuntu is

```
sudo apt-get install bjam
```

Extract the downloaded boost archive to your hard-drive and then cd into the root and

```
sudo bjam install
```

This way you can get the newest version of boost, and not the slightly outdated one that is available for your Ubuntu version.

Comment: I can't get bjam...when I type `sudo apt-get bjam` it says that bjam is an invalid operation

Comment: Oops, omitted "install", fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a link which explain step by step on how to install it (give it some time read!)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

but your inline shell command might be the simple and easy way for doing it